# About Spring WebClient on external onTerminate event

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm running a spring-boot v2.0.3 tomcat-embedded webserver 8.5.31, to Serve Spring Webflux REST services.
One of those REST services calls to another, external REST Webservice.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> select(ServerRequest request) {
  return request.principal().cast(Authentication.class)
      .flatMap(principal ->
          client.get().uri(f -> buildUri(request, principal, request.queryParams(), f))
              .exchange())
      .flatMap((ClientResponse mapper) ->
                  ServerResponse.status(mapper.statusCode())
                      .headers(c -> mapper.headers().asHttpHeaders().forEach(c::put))
                      .body(mapper.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
                          .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                          .doOnCancel(() -> log.error("Cancelled client"))
                          .doOnTerminate(() -> log.error("Terminated client")), DataBuffer.class))
      .doOnTerminate(() -> log.error("Termination called"));
}
```

If a browser calls my REST-Service, and after a short while cancels the connection, I can see the outer "Termination called" event, and that the client was terminated also.  But the client termination seems to trigger an error in tomcat:

```
2018-07-25 12:50:42.860 DEBUG 12084 --- [      elastic-3] org.example.search.security.UserManager       : Authorizing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken@809aec11: Principal: cn=dv dbsearch client, ou=dbsearch, o=example, l=eb, st=unknown, c=de; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: null; Not granted any authorities
2018-07-25 12:50:42.864 DEBUG 12084 --- [      elastic-3] org.example.search.security.UserManager       : Successfully authorized: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken@c03925ec: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@809aec0e: Username: cn=dv dbsearch client, ou=dbsearch, o=example, l=eb, st=unknown, c=de; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
2018-07-25 12:50:45.470 ERROR 12084 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.d.s.s.h.SolrSelectRequestHandler       : Termination called
2018-07-25 12:51:15.562 ERROR 12084 --- [     parallel-3] c.d.s.s.h.SolrSelectRequestHandler       : Terminated client
2018-07-25 12:51:15.625 ERROR 12084 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : Unhandled failure: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen, response already set (status=200)
2018-07-25 12:51:15.628  WARN 12084 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.s.h.s.r.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter      : Handling completed with error: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen
2018-07-25 12:51:15.652 ERROR 12084 --- [nio-8443-exec-2] o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter     : Exception while processing an asynchronous request

  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling [asyncError()] is not valid for a request with Async state [DISPATCHING]
  at org.apache.coyote.AsyncStateMachine.asyncError(AsyncStateMachine.java:424)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:470)
  at org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:431)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.setErrorState(AsyncContextImpl.java:388)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:176)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:232)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Sorry for the german errormessages, it means "client abortet connection".

I don't really have a problem with this errormessage per se, it's just, that my buffers in spring's Webclient don't seem to be cleared up (the log I did not reproduce locally, so it has diferent timestamps):

```
2018-07-23 08:44:36.892 ERROR 22707 — [reactor-http-nio-5] io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector       : LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.

Recent access records:

Created at:
   io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:331)      io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:185)
```

So here the question: How can I cleanly end the WebClient connection, when the request to my REST-Service is cancelled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really say for sure about that exception message, but I know Tomcat improved this in the 8.5.x generation. Which version are you using? If you can provide a consistent way to reproduce this with a minimal application, you could create a new issue in jira.spring.io on Spring Framework, or Tomcat itself if you managed to reproduce it without Spring (although it should be a hard one to reproduce).

Now about releasing `DataBuffer` instances - `DataBuffer` instances can be pooled, depending on the implementation. Here the `WebClient` is using Netty, which is pooling buffers. So they need to be released when they're no longer used.

Looking at your implementation, I think those unreleased buffers come from this:

- the `WebClient` is fetching data from the remote endpoint and creating `DataBuffer` instances
- various Reactor operators along the way are buffering those using internal queues (depending on the prefetching and the operators used, the amount of queued buffers can vary)
- when the subscriber fails or cancels, those buffers sitting in internal queues are not released as they should.

Currently Reactor does not offer a hook point to reach those objects in those error cases. But this is a brand new feature that's been added in Reactor core 3.2.0. This will be leveraged internally by Spring Framework with [SPR-17025](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17025). Please follow this issue - your use case might be handy when it comes to testing the fix.

Comment: I added the versions - thanks for the link to the spring issue, I'll definitely follow it!